# Macos get pointer being realloc'd was not allocated error in gas assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I am writing a simple compiler for gas assembly on macos which generated this assembly:

```
    .section __TEXT, __text
    .globl _print
_print:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movb $0, %al
    call _printf
    xorl %eax, %eax
    popq %rbp
    retq
str0:
    .asciz ""
    .globl _main
_main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    leaq str0(%rip), %rax
    movq %rax, 0(%rbp)
    movq ___stdinp@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq $0, 1(%rbp)
    movq (%rax), %rdx
    leaq 2(%rbp), %rdi
    leaq 1(%rbp), %rsi
    callq _getline
    movq 0(%rbp), %rsi
    movq 0(%rbp), %rdi
    callq _print
    xorl %eax, %eax
    popq %rbp
    retq
.subsections_via_symbols
```

And run it using:

`gcc -c main.s -o main.o`
`gcc main.o -o main`
`./main`

But whenever I use ./main I get: `main(13366,0x1132f8e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x5f00000000000000: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated main(13366,0x1132f8e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I don't know what I could do to fix this and have no idea what is going wrong so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `popq %rdi` <-- That stack is Last In First Out. So what you're popping here is the old value of `rbp` which you pushed two lines earlier. Why not just pass the argument in `rdi` from `_main` to `print` as well?

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the args you're passing to printf, and what you're doing to stack memory.  e.g. you're passing the frame pointer instead of a qword from above your return address.  Also, it's weird to use a stack-args calling convention for your own functions, instead of register args like the x86-64 System V calling convention specifies.  But if you are, it's easier to use push instead of manual stores.

Comment: @PeterCordes how would I do the push and pop?

Comment: Look at C compiler output for a function call with more than 6 args, e.g. to printf.  https://godbolt.org/z/vGT7Ye144.  You don't normally pop, except as part of saving/restoring a register.